# Keep Ricoh Aficio SP C240DN printing with low toner

Tags: printing, printer

When toner is low the printer shows a warning which requires you to press the Start button on the front of the printer before it will print every document. Is there a way to bypass this so it keeps printing until it actually is out of toner?

I appreciate there is a chip on the toner cartridge that is counting down and it won't keep printing when this hits zero but until that time I would love to not have to keep pressing Start every time I print.

Comment: Shaking the toner cartridge may help trick some sensors. A counting sensor might be harder to trick via such a method, though. Maybe an arduino to poke the start button via a servo? Stupid printer vendors...

Comment: http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view4/2239283/homer-bird-o.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @michael hampton [http://www.amazon.com/Drinking-Bird-4975-The-Famous/dp/B000JSGLBK/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JSGLBK)